# Formula field to separate strings in a Text field?

Tags: formula-field

I'm stuck with a problem:

I have a text field that has `Names_c =Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4`

How can I split those four names using separate formula fields?

ex: `Firstname=Test1, Secondname=Test2, Thirdname=Test3, Fourthname=Test4`

anyone help me please

Comment: Trigger unless someone has some hacked together formula

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this in Apex, but if you must use formula fileds, you can use this to get the first three formulas that separate the commas:

```
First_Name__c  -> TRIM(LEFT(Names__c , FIND(",", Names__c)-1))
Second_Name__c -> LEFT(RIGHT(Names__c, LEN(Names__c) - FIND (",", Names__c)), FIND("," , RIGHT(Names__c, LEN(Names__c) - FIND (",", Names__c)))-1)
Third_Name__c  -> LEFT(RIGHT(Names__c, LEN(RIGHT(Names__c, LEN(Names__c) - FIND (",", Names__c))) - FIND (",", RIGHT(Names__c, LEN(Names__c) - FIND (",", Names__c)))), FIND("," , RIGHT(Names__c, LEN(RIGHT(Names__c, LEN(Names__c) - FIND (",", Names__c))) - FIND (",", RIGHT(Names__c, LEN(Names__c) - FIND (",", Names__c)))))-1)
```

It won't be hard for you to work out how to get the fourth using this pattern.please read before come

Hope this helps!

[image: f.ex.]

Comment: but third one is not working

Comment: What's your problem with it? Can you ellaborate? It worked on the simple test I made.